# USB to serial converter using the CDC/ACM specification

Tags: usb, serial, rs232

I am trying to use a USB to serial converter in a Windows store application. As the Windows store application does not support serial ports, I need to find a USB/serial converter that supports CDC/ACM.

Here is what I tried:

- Create a customer inf file for a FTDI controlled serial converter (which didn't work because I later found out that FTDI does not support CDC)
- Find a serial converter that supports CDC (I didn't have any luck with that either.)

Can somebody tell me where I can get a CDC compatible USB/serial converter?

Comment: afaik, actual cdc was poorly implemented, and not widely received by manufacturers. The major three makers (ftdi ft232, sl cp2101, and pl2303) use their own drivers and cdc-like implementations. I think that maybe the microchip mcp2200 can use the actual cdc-acm specs and drivers. HTH.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about EE

Comment: @andyaka the answer likely is - almost any microcontroller with usb capability has a cdc/acm serial converter as a demo project.  So building some hardware (or at least repurposing an eval board) seems likely.

Comment: @Passerby that the cdc was poorly implemented is something i sadly read a lot. The MCP2200 USB to RS232 Demo Board seems to do the job althaught we can't sell a unprotected print to our customers. Maybe there is some more complete solution

Comment: @console unprotected print? I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure of what that means.

Comment: @Passerby I look for a complete chip set in a case with a USB and a DB9 plug. Similar to those offered for ftdi/prolific chips.

Comment: Allegedly, some of the FTDI chips can be put into a CDC/ACM mode, by command or perhaps by programming an internal or external configuration EEPROM.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for that. Maybe you can give me some more Details where i have to look to get that done? As i am no not used to µC programming.

Comment: You'd have to look in the FTDI documentation. It's not something I've ever tried, just remember seeing mention of.

Comment: Are you able to load usb drivers in your OS?  You can simply turn off the serial port feature of the FTDI (FT_PROG.EXE) and windows will load the D2XX driver instead.

Comment: @console, you say you're looking for a "complete chip set in a case with a USB and DB9 plug". Am I right in concluding that you are looking for a complete product you can readily sell to your customers? EE.SE is hardly the right place for that question. You might want to try SuperUser or ServerFault, as USB to Serial converters are end-user equipment.

Comment: USB 2 Serial converter with ATMEGA 8u2
http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/USB-2-Serial-Converter-p-1482.html?cPath=63_66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microchip MCP2200](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en546923) is an FDTI-like device that implements CDC protocol.

Otherwise, you can choose a USB-capable microcontroller from a manufacturer that supplies CDC example code.  (This will be most manufacturers that sell USB-capable micros.)

Comment: Somebody already suggested the MCP2200 as there is a demo board with a usb and a DB9 plug. We ordered one i will take a closer look as it arives.

Comment: Does the MCP2200 support XON / XOFF ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use the[Arduino leonardo](http://arduino.cc/de/Guide/ArduinoLeonardo) board since the product guide says " The Leonardo is an instance of USB's Connected Device Class (CDC) driver." And then just use the [RS232 Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11958) to get the level shifting for RS232.

Comment: Workable, but quite expensive and bulky

Answer (score 0):

http://sabrent.com/category/cables/CB-FTDI/

That device appears to support CDC mode natively:

> Compatible with USB Specification v1.1(0) & USB CDC v1.1, USB 2.0

It comes with a driver CD, but in the description is another interesting line:

> Utilizes the FTDI chipset; plug and play, **driverless** installation.

Comment: I have seen that too, but it seems to be wrong information. Allthought i will give it a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Exar makes USB UART chips that support CDC/ACM.  However, you have to watch out as they come up with hardware flow control enabled and you can't turn it off unless you use their proprietary driver.  If you don't need it, just make sure you tie off the flow control pins properly and it isn't an issue.

http://www.exar.com/connectivity/uart-and-bridging-solutions/usb-uarts/xr21v1410

I'm not aware of any particular USB to serial cables that use this chipset, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some options that I am aware of:

- [MCP2200](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/200022228D.pdf) (20-pin VQFN/SOIC, USB CDC+HID, UART + GPIO, 2×64 buffer, external crystal required)
- [MCP2221A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005565A.pdf) (16-pin VQFN/SOIC/DIP, USB CDC+HID, UART + GPIO + I2C, 64+384 buffer)
- [CY7C65213/A](https://www.cypress.com/file/139881/download) (SSOP-28/QFN-32, USB CDC, 2×256 buffer, pin-for-pin FT232R replacement)

Answer (score 0):

The ST-Link debugger that is included in STM32 Nucleo dev-boards also includes a USB-serial converter that uses the CDC-ACM spec.

For example this one: https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-g071rb.html

The main use case is to have a Serial connection to the target microcontroller, but you can also feed external signals to the TX and RX headers on the ST-Link daughter board.